# ArrayList as Parameter

Tags: java, jdbc

Can someone help me to convert this into a method?

```java
List<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {        
    listName.add(rs.getString("columnName"));
}
System.out.println(listName);
```

I tried l, but only the first List will be printed with contents. The next prints only as [].

Comment: what is `rs` here? This semi colon is not required `rs.getString("columnName");`, because this is passed as method parameter.

Comment: What is your variable `rs`? Damn, @YoungHobbit beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it. rs is the ResultSet. I'm getting the contents of a column from a database.

Comment: @YoungHobbit sorry mistyped it as I edited some part before posting this using my iPhone.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 it is the ResultSet interface. Sorry forgot to add it in the snippet.

Comment: This is the correct statement `listName.add(rs.getString("columnName"));`

Comment: if solution works for you then you can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List feedResultIntoList(List<String> myList , ResultSet rs){

        if(rs == null || myList == null)
        return null;

        else{

        while (rs.next()) {        
                 myList.add(rs.getString("columnName"));
        }
        System.out.println(myList);
        return myList;
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to make listName as paramater too as I will be dealing with many lists.

Comment: updated my answer, but here you can also improve your list paramter to be of any type, not only restricted to String

Comment: Thanks, although this always give me null. The problem is my rs is always null.

Comment: Can the ArrayList be used as parameter without instantiating it inside the method?

Comment: yes you can use it, as I am using the same way (not instantiating it inside) but in that case you must have a null check otherwise will cause Null pointer excption

Comment: oh I see, get it now. Thanks Sir.